# How to relate the duplicate records to the input records using the Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates Apex API?

Tags: apex, duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule, findduplicates

This [FindDuplicates Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicates.htm#apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicates) has a `findDuplicates`  method that returns existing duplicate records (rom the database) for one or more input records (that are not in the database):

```
List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult> findDuplicates(List<SObject> inputs)
```

Calling this with a single record in `inputs` means you know that the duplicates relate to that input. But if `inputs` includes many records, I don't see a way of relating each input to its duplicates.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked seems to indicate:

> The output of FindDuplicates is an **array of objects with the same number of elements as the input array, and in the same order**. The output objects encapsulate record IDs for duplicate records. The output objects also contain values from the duplicate records.

The [FindDuplicatesResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicatesResult.htm#apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicatesResult) then shows using [getDuplicateResults](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicatesResult.htm#apex_Datacloud_FindDuplicatesResult_getDuplicateResults) for each element in the array to get the "duplicates" (example code taken from documentation). Presumably, since the order is matched between input/output - you should be able to build out a map of the input and its related duplicate output.

```java
Account acct = new Account(name='Salesforce');
List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
acctList.add(acct);

Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult[] results = Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates(acctList);
for (Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult findDupeResult : results) {
  for (Datacloud.DuplicateResult dupeResult : findDupeResult.getDuplicateResults()) {
    for (Datacloud.MatchResult matchResult : dupeResult.getMatchResults()) {
      for (Datacloud.MatchRecord matchRecord : matchResult.getMatchRecords()) {
          System.debug('Duplicate Record: ' + matchRecord.getRecord());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Based on the above example code - I can see why the input array is limited to 50 elements.

> The input array is limited to 50 elements. If you exceed this limit, an exception is thrown with the following message: Configuration error: The number of records to check is greater than the permitted batch size.

Comment: Thanks Kris - completely missed that. Does explain the multiple levels of nesting of the results...